# Synchronize access to static variables in sql server SQLCLR

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, sqlclr

I have written an assembly which is integrated in sql server, providing some stored procedures written in C#. The assembly has a readonly static variable holding some configuration data. This data is manipulated via stored procedures, which are also provided by the assembly. Obviously I have to synchronize access to this static variable. I tried to use

```
lock(someGuard)
{
    // ... access static configuration
}
```

inside my configuration class. But then I get a HostProtectionException, telling me, that the assembly has to run with full trust to do that. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually an undocumented hack: decorate the class with the [`CompilerGenerated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute.aspx) attribute. As with any undocumented workarounds, mileage may vary with future releases.

You shouldn't need this though, if the static is readonly then you can declare it readonly and the assembly will deploy fine, readonly statics are accepted in SAFE assemblies. And is truly readonly, the lock guard is also unnecessary.

If you cannot mark it readonly and remove the lock, it means is not readonly and you will be on moving sands territory. You can block SQL workers and have unpredictable results (hence the UNSAFE requirement). The CompilerGenerated trick should really be used with a **lot** of care, onyl if you understand perfectly the implications. The fact that you need a `lock` is a strong indicator your code is actually unsafe wrt to SQL and statics.

Comment: Though *technically* it does seem to be documented.  :-)  Probably not supported for this use though.

Comment: Yes, it does say `This attribute allows SQL server to reference compiler-generated static values`. AFAIK this is the only use for this attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My variable is readonly, but it's internal state changes. It holds some configuration options which I want to read only once. Is there some possibility to execute code at startup of the appdomain? In that case my configuration would realy be readonly and my problem would have gone.

Comment: @Achim: can't you read the configuration at the read only object initialization? eg: `static readonly MyClass myField = MyClass.ReadConfig()`.

Comment: @Remus: I'll try that. Can I already access the database at that moment? Will check it. Sql server 2005 and 2008 seem to behave a bit different regarding static variable checking.

Answer (score 2):

The only way around this restriction is to deploy the assembly as UNSAFE. Still, static shared data is against recommendations:

> The programming model for managed code
>   in SQL Server requires functions,
>   procedures, and types which do not
>   require the use of state held across
>   multiple invocations or the sharing of
>   state across multiple user sessions.
>   Further, as described earlier, the
>   presence of shared state can cause
>   critical exceptions that impact the
>   scalability and the reliability of the
>   application.
>
> Given these considerations, SQL Server
>   disallows the use of static variables
>   and static data members. For SAFE and
>   EXTERNAL-ACCESS assemblies, SQL Server
>   examines the metadata of the assembly
>   at CREATE ASSEMBLY time, and fails the
>   creation of such assemblies if it
>   finds the use of static data members
>   and variables.